# Stop Outlook from sending email when adding ics to calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, privacy, ics

When I download an invitation to an appointment as ics file, open it in outlook and save it to my calendar, behind the scences an email is sent out to the organisator. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment but cannot reproduce your issue. Did you select "Accept" > "Send the Response Now"?

Comment: No, I just klicked save in the appointment. I know it's trying to send an email, because I'm signing my emails via PKI and the PIN dialogue pops up.